# Tomcat cannot serve files over 1MB without breaking under high load

Tags: solaris, tomcat6

For some reason, my tomcat deployment begins throwing `BadFileNumber` exceptions when a large file (>1MB) is served over high load. I'm using `JRE 1.6.0_17` with `Tomcat 6.0.14`. What could possibly cause tomcat to serve bad files under high load for large files?

Comment: take a look at this [post](http://serverfault.com/questions/95822/unusual-apache-tomcat-caching-issue) from serverfault. it seems to be the same problem. for quick reference: the [link](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/tomcat-dev/200808.mbox/%3Cbug-45601-78@https.issues.apache.org/bugzilla/%3E) to the bug report mentioned in the post.

Comment: This is a rewording of that problem, and the provided bugfix does not work. I'm hoping someone else has an actual solution to this specific issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fix for this issue has been added to the 6.0.x and 5.5.x source line. This was fixed in glassfish, but it was never backported to Tomcat.